# purging from font cache when relaunching activity

Tags: android, fonts, android-asynctask, android-activity

When the my application launches for the first time after installation, it works good, but when the user relaunches it after closing, the application hangs on first activity for some time and runs slow, giving the Logs of **purging from font cache**, It happens only on first activity.
In the first activity, I am downloading strings and images from a web-service and showing the data in a `TableLayout` in dynamically created `TableRow`. I am using a custom font (Halvetica bold, if it matters) for showing data. The `ScrollView` in which I am putting the `TableLayout`, doesn't scrolls on relaunching for few seconds and sometimes triggers the ANR.
I am using `AsyncTask` for downloading those data. Is there any way I can stop this purging or relaunch the activity as if it's getting launched for the first time after installation??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this. The problem was I was using a static class, which was not getting reset and due to that the `TableRow` was getting piled up, affecting the performance.
So I declared a new `reset()` method in that static class and called it in `onDestroy()`.
Additionally I converted the whole `TableLayout` + `ScrollView` into a `ListView` which has a `recycle` feature. Now the application is working excellent.